# matplotlib automatically sorting time values

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to plot data from temperature sensor with time steps. I have time steps in format "hh:mm:ss" after conversion from string to datetime format. First value in the list is "21:47:22" and the last one is "06:12:22" the next day.I have been trying to plot these values with order of indexes in the list however Python automaticaly sorting it from "00:00:00" to "24:00:00" on the x axis. Here is the image.[image]
Could you please advice how to solve this issue? Below my code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import datetime

data = []
sensor1 = []
sensor2 = []
time = []

with open("output.txt","r") as f:
   data = f.readlines()

first_sensor_len = len(data[0])

for var in data:
    if var[2:7] == "First" and len(var) == first_sensor_len:
        sensor1.append(var[28:33])
        sensor2.append(var[75:80])
        time.append(datetime.datetime.strptime(var[36:44], "%H:%M:%S"))
    elif var[2:8] == "Second" and len(var) == first_sensor_len:
        sensor2.append(var[29:34])
        sensor1.append(var[75:80])
        time.append(datetime.datetime.strptime(var[83:91], "%H:%M:%S"))

plt.plot(time, sensor1)

plt.show()
```

Comment: There's no way for python to automatically guess that those dates correspond to different days. You probably have to fix that yourself, such as taking all the values that are earlier than your _first_ datetime and shift them by a day's worth of a timedelta.

Comment: Matplotlib can in general plot `datetime` objects. It has no suppoer for times. You need to attach a date to your times.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Supposed `time` looks like

```
timestr = ["21:47:22", "22:12:22", "23:12:22", "00:12:22", "01:12:22", "03:12:22", "06:12:22"]
time = [datetime.datetime.strptime(ts, "%H:%M:%S") for ts in timestr]

time
[datetime.datetime(1900, 1, 1, 21, 47, 22),
 datetime.datetime(1900, 1, 1, 22, 12, 22),
 datetime.datetime(1900, 1, 1, 23, 12, 22),
 datetime.datetime(1900, 1, 1, 0, 12, 22),
 datetime.datetime(1900, 1, 1, 1, 12, 22),
 datetime.datetime(1900, 1, 1, 3, 12, 22),
 datetime.datetime(1900, 1, 1, 6, 12, 22)]
```

You can use `np.diff` from `numpy` to mark every first time of a new day. If the difference of two consecutive time values is negative, there was midnight in between.
(This boolean array is appended to one initial `False`, which states that the first time value has always no day offset; the result of `np.diff` is generally one entry shorter than its input.)

```
import numpy as np
newday_marker = np.append(False, np.diff(time) < datetime.timedelta(0))

newday_marker
array([False, False, False,  True, False, False, False], dtype=bool)
```

With `np.cumsum` this array can be transformed into the array of dayoffsets for each time value.

```
day_offset = np.cumsum(newday_marker)

day_offset
array([0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1], dtype=int32)
```

In the end this has to be converted to timedeltas and then can be added to the original list of time values:

```
date_offset = [datetime.timedelta(int(dt)) for dt in day_offset]
dtime = [t + dos for t, dos in zip(time, date_offset)]

dtime
[datetime.datetime(1900, 1, 1, 21, 47, 22),
 datetime.datetime(1900, 1, 1, 22, 12, 22),
 datetime.datetime(1900, 1, 1, 23, 12, 22),
 datetime.datetime(1900, 1, 2, 0, 12, 22),
 datetime.datetime(1900, 1, 2, 1, 12, 22),
 datetime.datetime(1900, 1, 2, 3, 12, 22),
 datetime.datetime(1900, 1, 2, 6, 12, 22)]
```